# How to insert a column containing variable relations instead of records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables

I want a column to be inserted **before description column**. And I want it to be like this:

```
///Totalcolumn = QNTColumn * UnitCostColumn///
```

I don't want it to contain only one record.

This will talk for me:

```
CREATE PRCOEDURE GetAllGoods
AS
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY namecolumn) AS RowNumberColumn,
        CodeColumn,
        NameColumn,
        SUM(QTYColumn) AS Total_QTY,
        UnitCostColumn,
        DiscountRateColumn,
        **->INSERT HERE (Total_QTY) * UnitCost AS Total_Cost
        DescriptionColumn
    FROM 
        GoodsTable1
```

Comment: Sapmle data and desired results would be much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do try this

```
SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY namecolumn) AS RowNumberColumn,
        CodeColumn,
        NameColumn,
        SUM(QTYColumn) AS Total_QTY,
        UnitCostColumn,
        DiscountRateColumn,
        sum(QTYColumn) * UnitCostColumn AS Total_Cost,
        DescriptionColumn
    FROM 
        GoodsTable1
    GROUP BY
         CodeColumn, NameColumn, UnitCostColumn, DiscountRateColumn, DescriptionColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for some kind of use of [window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Generally, you are able use particular aggregate functions with conjunction with the `OVER` clause. This allows you to get aggregates on row level, without specifying `GROUP BY` clause.

For [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#b-using-the-over-clause) you can calculate a cumulative total, too. In your case, I guess you can use `PARTITION BY` to calculate the `Total_QTY` for particular kind of item. I believe you will manage to handle this as you are using well ranking functions (the concept is the same).

So, you can try something like this:

```
SUM(QTYColumn) OVER () * UnitCost
```

if the data is already filter for particular items or:

```
SUM(QTYColumn) OVER (PARTITION BY itemID) * UnitCost
```